# Interface implementation with a method containing a non-exported parameter type (Java 9 modules)

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am using the Java 9 module system. Below is a simplified version of my problem.

I have defined `ClassA` (in module `com.foo`) to implement `InterfaceB` (in module `com.bar`). `ClassA` implements the method `print` of `InterfaceB`, which take a parameter of type `ClassC` (in module `com.baz`). Below is the code.

```
// src/a/com/foo/ClassA.java
package com.foo;

import com.bar.InterfaceB;
import com.baz.ClassC;

public class ClassA implements InterfaceB {
    @Override
    public void print(ClassC obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
} 


// src/b/com/bar/InterfaceB.java
package com.bar;

import com.baz.ClassC;

public interface InterfaceB {
    public void print(ClassC obj);
}


// src/c/com/baz/ClassC.java
package com.baz;

public class ClassC {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This is a ClassC object";
    }
}
```

The `com.baz` module does not export anything. So, in order to access `ClassC` during the compilation of `InterfaceB` and `ClassA`, I use the `--add-exports` flag.

`InterfaceB` successfully compiles, but when I then try to compile `ClassA`, I receive the error:

```
src/a/com/foo/ClassA.java:6: ClassA is not abstract and does not override abstract method print(ClassC) in InterfaceB
```

Is the compiler somehow using different instances of `ClassC`? I have a feeling something unexpected is happening with `--add-exports`.

(As a side note, the reason I'm using `--add-exports` is that, in my example, `com.baz` is actually an internal JDK package. I am unable to modify the module settings to export it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are indeed ways to get the module system to compile your code ([you found it already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924121/2525313)), you will find similar problems at run time when, again, code calling `InterfaceB::print` can not access `ClassC`. Again, command line flags can be used to fix that. *But they shouldn't!*

The module system is trying to tell you something, here: *"This modularization is broken!"*

If *any* module outside of `com.baz` should be allowed to use `ClassC`, then the package containing it should be exported! This is exactly what exports are for. Other code clearly depends on `ClassC` and the module system was built to make such dependencies explicit. So unless you're doing this in an exercise to get to know the command line overrides, the real solution is to have *com.baz* export `com.baz`.

(If not all modules should see it, consider [qualified exports](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#qualified-exports). If reflection is involved, other approaches might be better suited and a new question should be asked.)

Comment: I simplified my question a little. The packages which are not exported are part of the internal JDK API, so I cannot change the settings of their module to export them. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: No, no simpler way. This is intentionally hard because you should not do it unless people's lives are on the line. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why the error occurs or if it is intended or not, but I did find a solution.

While compiling `ClassA`, *also* exporting the `com.baz` module to `com.bar` (where `InterfaceB` is) seems to allow the compiler to see the correct `ClassC` class.

e.g.

```
-javac ... --add-exports com.baz/com.baz=com.foo,com.bar
```